# How to view my entire blog?

Tags: history, blogging

I have a blog on blogspot.  I am looking into printing this myself.

This would be a lot easier to do if there was a way to view the entire blog history on one page.  Can this be done?

Comment: This is a website support issue. Not in the scope of SU.

Comment: Hmmmm, OK but :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i were you i would grab the whole blog via gdata-api, perhaps as xml-document and transform it via xslt into fo and then that to pdf:

- http://your.blog.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=5